# npm throws error for wrong package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

Previously, I tried installing the package `react-bootstrap`, but since it wasn't compatible with my version of react I gave up.

However, now I get the following error when running `npm install` for any package:

```
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package react does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer react-bootstrap@0.27.1 wants react@>=0.14.0
```

This happens even though `react-bootstrap` is not actually installed.
It is NOT listed in `package.json`. In this file I only specify the version of react:

```
react": "~0.13.3"
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: You may want to include the `package.json` as well.

Comment: I updated my response.

Comment: Why don't you use react 0.14?

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall `react-bootstrap` then install its latest version working with react v0.13.x

```
npm uninstall react-bootstrap
npm install react-bootstrap@0.26.4 --save
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to delete the `node_modules` file containing all npm packages. Then, I had to run `npm install`